What happens to output signal if the filter has a large time delay
I am practicing FIR filter design using the frequency equivalence method. I have designed a lowpass filter with order 20000 with passband 0 - 250 Hz. I send the signal $x(t) = \sin(2\pi t) + \sin(300 \cdot 2\pi t) $ through the filter. Both sinusoidal signals are sampled with $f_s = 1000 \: \text{Hz}$. I expect the high frequency component to be very attenuated, but something else weird happens in the "beginning" of the output signal. Here is the frequency response and input signal: -

And here is the output signal: -

Why does the output signal only look like $\sin(2\pi t)$ after approximately 10 seconds? It must be something to do with the time delay of the FIR filter, but what exactly?
Edit
I am not asking why the $\sin(2\pi t)$ signal is delayed by 10 seconds. That is obvious and I am aware that a linear derivative of the phase response results in a uniform delay for all signals in the passband. What I am asking is why my signal looks weird in the first 10 seconds. If the input is delayed 10 seconds with repsect to the output, why do I not just see a flat line at the output in the first 10 seconds? What is this low-amplitude sinusoidal wave I'm seeing?

Please edit your question with the sampling rate so we know what the time delay is.  While you're waiting for a response, look at the title of your question, and compare that with the filter not showing a response for a good long time.  Maybe look up the definition of the word "delay" in a dictionary.

@TimWescott I updated the question. What do you mean by "the filter not showing a response for a good long time"? It clearly does show a response, but it is a very low-amplitude signal compared to its appearance after 10 seconds.

10000 samples at 1000hz is 10s… google ”FIR filter delay”? I’m not sure why you haven’t already

@Jdip Yes, that is obvious. I'm asking why the output signal has a low-amplitude sinusoidal appearance in the first 10 seconds. If there is a 10 seconds delay why do I not just see a flat line until 10 seconds and then the output signal "wakes up"?

Ah, I see ok. I think Dan answered that question then.

We would not expect to see zeros at the output of an FIR filter since the output at any time for an FIR filter is the weighted samples of the current input and the past $N-1$ inputs, where $N$ is the number of taps in the FIR filter. So the output that is shown is what would be expected up until the filter is nearly half full where the dominant taps of the linear phase half-band filter reside, at which time the summation accumulates to the more significant values shown as samples continue to stream through the filter.
Consider how the filter designed (a half-band filter with a nearly brickwall response) will have an impulse response (coefficients of the filter) that will be close to a Sinc function with a relatively small main lobe (given that a Sinc in the time domain is a rectangular function in the frequency domain). Thus a majority of the coefficients will be of relatively small values, and summing the coefficients on one side of the Sinc will also sum to a small value. It is not until the filter reaches the center (the peak of the Sinc) where we will then see a large value at the output, and as we continue to sum over both sides of the Sinc function, for signals within the passband of the filter, the result will be the normalized gain that we expect.
To demonstrate this I created a 1001 tap half-band filter which has the coefficients as plotted below, and below that is the cumulative sum of the coefficients. If we were to pass all ones into the filter (DC), then it would be the sum of the coefficients exactly that we would see at the output of the filter.

Zooming in on the first accumulated samples we see:

This is significantly smaller than the OP's but this is also why I do not recommend using the Frequency Sampling approach to design FIR filters. This filter I created was designed using the least squares algorithm (firls in MATLAB, Octave and Python scipy.signal), resulting in a significantly better frequency response with significantly fewer coefficients as demonstrated in the plot below. It is this poorer rejection in the OP's response that results in greater ripple at the starting transient (first 10 seconds).  To note it is a useful technique to estimate the impulse response with an inverse FFT of the desired frequency response when the impulse response isn't otherwise known, and then use that with the "Windowing" approach to filter design as described in the linked post above. This is in sharp contrast to using the inverse FFT as the coefficients for the FIR filter directly.

